# knockout js visible doesnt seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am pretty new to knockout, i am trying to hide or show a label which is on a slider item based on a condition. Even the value evaluates to false i still see the label. Any suggestion appreciated.

Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $slidersTest = $('[pw-class="slider-image"]');

    if ($slidersTest ) {
        $slidersTest .each(function () {
            var $slider = $(this);
            var slider = new SliderModel();

            slider.items = [
                @foreach (var i in Model.Test)
            {
                    <text>
                        new ThumbnailModel(
                        {
                            "label": " @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(@i.content))
                                       {
                                           @i.content
                                       }
                                       else if ((string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(@i.content) && (DateTime.Now - @i.CreatedDate).TotalDays < 7))
                                       {
                                           @content
                                       }",                                                                                

                            "Title": "@Model.Title",

        }),
        </text>
        }
        ];

        ko.applyBindings(slider, $slider[0]);
        });

    (function ($) {
        $slidersTest .each(function () {
            $slidersTest .pwSlider();
        });
    })(jQuery);
}
    });
```

Here is the label where i am checking on the label value if the value is null or empty i want the label to hide completely.

```
<p class="pw-label" data-bind="visible: ($root.label != null || $root.label !='' )"><span class="pw-text" >Label: </span><!-- ko text: label --><!-- /ko --></p>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow your code but at the very least label needs to be an observable, otherwise your markup won't know that it has changed.